# Why is the variable not being applied to the environment of the command that follows it?

Tags: bash

For the commands:

```
z=bye
z=hello echo $z
echo $z
```

I'm expecting to see:

```
hello
bye
```

Instead, I'm seeing:

```
bye
bye
```

According to the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) (emphasis mine):

> #### 3.7.1 Simple Command Expansion
>
> When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following
> expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right, in the
> following order.
>
> 1. The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and redirections are saved for later
>    processing.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded (see Shell Expansions). If any words remain after expansion,
>    the first word is taken to be the name of the command and the
>    remaining words are the arguments.
> 3. Redirections are performed as described above (see Redirections).
> 4. The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>    expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.
>
> If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the
> current shell environment. In the case of such a command (one that
> consists only of assignment statements and redirections), assignment
> statements are performed before redirections. ***Otherwise, the variables
> are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect
> the current shell environment.*** If any of the assignments attempts to
> assign a value to a readonly variable, an error occurs, and the
> command exits with a non-zero status.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's get the man page. According to the man page https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation :

> the shell does the following:
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Performs the various shell expansions (see Shell Expansions), breaking the expanded tokens into lists of filenames (see Filename Expansion) and commands and arguments.
>
> [...]
>
> 6. Executes the command (see Executing Commands).

First `z=hello echo $z` is expanded to `z=hello echo bye`. *Then* `z=hello` is assigned and exported, and then `echo bye` is executed. So the output is `bye`, the variable `z` is expanded before it is assigned for the current command.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the reason seems to be that the line gets expanded in the context of the line.  Not the context of the execution.  To see this work, I would have to have a separate function/script to see the change.

```
fn() { echo $z; }
z=bye
z=hello fn
echo $z
```

Gives me the output that I was expecting.

Comment: Some alternative ways to achieve the same: `z=hello  bash -c 'echo $z'`, `z=hello  printenv z`